# What is a child combinators in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in studying CSS.
**I want to make only child1 red.**

as I know div is parents.
`p` and `span.bbb` is child combinators.
span.aaa is descendant combinators.
and then
`A>B` is to select child combinators.
A B is to select descendant combinators.

If I choose `div>p`, I thought it would be what I wanted.
But both child1 and descendant turned red.
**Where am I wrong?**

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
div>p{
  color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="VIEWPORT" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<tilte>combinators.html</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='combinators.css'>
</head>
<body>
<div>parents
  <p>child1
    <span class='aaa'>descendant
    </span>
  </p>
  <span class='bbb'>child2
  </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: color is inherited

Comment: That's the "cascading" part of CSS. ;)

Comment: The `color` property has `inherit` As default for many elements.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try

div>p:nth-child(1) { }

For more child css selectors check https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

Comment: Let me ask you one more thing. I think it's parents=div / child combinator=p, span.bbb / descendant combinator=p, span.bbb, span.aaa, right?

Comment: According to this definition . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators I do not see difference between the selectors you are comparing, please provide two different examples as code reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not good at English, but I'll try my best to read.

Answer (score -1):

I posted 2 example of CSS property. I hope help this.

Example-1

```
div > p > span {
  color: #f00;
}
```

---

Example-2

```
div > p > span:nth-child(1) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Thanks and I should have made the question more clear, sorry.